# PostgreSQL: trigger to call function with parameters

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

In PostgreSQL, I'm trying to create a trigger that passes an argument to a function, but it appears that this operation looks for a function whose signature has zero arguments:

```
ERROR:  function create_rec_if_needed() does not exist: 
      CREATE TRIGGER after_update_winks AFTER UPDATE ON winks
      FOR EACH ROW
      WHEN (NEW.counter > 3)
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_rec_if_needed(NEW.id, 'Wink')
```

When I list extant functions, I can see my 2-argument function. Here's the output of `\df`:

```
                                                          List of functions
 Schema |          Name           |     Result data type      |                          Argument data types    
--------+-------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------------
 public | create_rec_if_needed    | void                      | rec_id integer, rec_type text
```

Can anyone shed a bit of light on why my trigger isn't making use of the existing function? Is there an alternative design I should use to reach my goal? My aim is for multiple tables to have a trigger that calls the function `create_rec_if_needed`, and in each case, the trigger must supply the id of the record and a table-specific string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A trigger procedure is created with the CREATE FUNCTION command,
>   declaring it as a function with no arguments and a return type of
>   trigger.

You can use the arguments passed to the trigger function via `TG_ARGV`, e.g. `TG_TABLE_NAME` - the name of the table that caused the trigger invocation. [40.9. Trigger Procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).